# Passing a Rails form POST data to a JS click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a simple form where the user can edit their profile data and click "Submit"

I have an intercepting click event on the submit button so that I can run some arbitrary client-side validations before continuing with the submit.

```
$(function() {

  $("body").on("click", "#user-profile input.submit", function(e) {
    // Prevent the submit from continuing
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do some validation stuff here
    //
    //

    // Assuming above was succesful, continue with original submit
    $("#user-profile form.edit_user").submit();
  });
});
```

I'd love to have access to the actual form data that was being `POST`-ed to the Submit button before I intercepted it. More specifically, the form contains several Rails nested attributes, so I'd love the data in the same nested format as well.

Are the form `POST` data params available here? Or am I stuck pulling data manually from the input fields using `$("css.selector").val()` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener to form event [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of click

```
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  var valid = true;
// Do some validation stuff here
//
//
  if (!this.inputName.value) valid = false;
// Prevent the submit from continuing if invalid
  if (!valid) e.preventDefault();
});
```

So if form elements are not valid `e.preventDefault();` will prevent submitting,  other way it will submit.

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to place the `preventDefault()` at the beginning so it stops the submit before any of the validation logic starts? And if I were to do that, is there a way to "re-trigger" the form submit again at the end, like `this.submit()` ?

Comment: It is preffered to prevent only if form values are not valid.

Comment: If you prevent at the beginning it won't work because it will go to the same handler first after triggering submit.